# Synchronize the parameter of a dynamic select list in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a form with a dynamically generated select list. The values for this list are retrieved from the scope. The currently selected value is also retrieved from the scope.

Unfortunately, there is a synchronization issue.

Below this is illustrated. The dynamic select list shows 1 as selected, but the param is 2. The static select list shows the correct value.

```js
angular.module('fiddle', [])
.controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.xs = [1,2,3];
    $scope.param = 2;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="fiddle" ng-controller="Ctrl">
     Correct representation:
     <select ng-model="param">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
    </select><br>
    Incorrect representation:
    <select ng-model="param">
        <option ng-repeat="x in xs" value="{{x}}">{{x}}</option>
    </select><br>
    param: {{param}}
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

As I was properly formulating my question, as often, I found the solution already.

I should use ng-options instead of ng-repeat on the option tag.

```
<select ng-model="param" ng-options="x for x in xs">
</select>
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select